# Custom AuthenticationProvider is not called

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to have a basic auth-protected REST app. I followed the general instructions from http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider in order to get the security working.

I ended up creating my implementation of `AuthenticationProvider`, but it never gets called by Spring. All requests end up with an error:

```
{"timestamp":1460199213227,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/test"}
```

without the AuthenticationProvider ever doing anything.

The app is annotation-based and here are the relevant bits:

**Security setup**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;
    @Autowired
    private Authenticator authenticator;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // This never gets called, I checked with debugger
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);
        User authenticatedUser = authenticator.authenticate(user, password);
        if (authenticatedUser == null){
            throw new RESTAuthenticationException("Auth failed");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, authorityList);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity test(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your @Configuration class you use a DeadlinesAuthenticationProvider, but you post the code of a CustomAuthenticationProvider. Isn't it your problem ?

Comment: I was editing the code by hand when posting, so that's just an error on my part, the code has it set correctly. Fixed

Comment: OK. How do you call the /test ? Are you using some tool like curl or are you using a browser or something else ?

Comment: According to the article you linked, it is sufficient to have the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method set up the custom authentication provider. So why are you explicitly calling `.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)` in your `HttpSecurity` configuration? Does it not work without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You receive a response with status code 401. This is the ["unauthorized" http status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2). It is probably caused by a missing/malformed Authorization header in your request.

You are using [Http-Basic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2): it requires the following header in the request :

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

where the string *QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l* is the string `<user>:<password>` base64 encoded.

Comment: I'll be damned. The header I was sending was `Authorization: Basic: <something>`... the extra colon was the problem.